# How to mimic click event of anchor tag in Vaadin flow?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am able to use Upload Component to upload file from page to my file system like below.

```
          return (MultiFileReceiver) (String fileName, String mimeType) -> {
          try {
              File file = new File(uploadFileDirectory,fileName);
              return fileOutputHandlerService.fileOutput(file);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
      };
```

But when it comes to download that file with given path I can't accomplish that.
Only explanation to do that is using Anchor element. but I want to use ContextMenu component to trigger a download .
I have a contextmenu Component derived from a Grid

```
 fileListContext = grid.addContextMenu();
 fileListContext.addItem("Download",uiListener.fileDownloadRequestListener());
```

I implemented that context menu listener like below. I want to click that context menu pop up and prompt browser to open save location for user to start download.

```
        private  ComponentEventListener <GridContextMenu.GridContextMenuItemClickEvent<FileEntity>>  fileDownloadRequestListener(){
      //created stream user and anchor element. how to trigger download attribute of anchor?
      return selectedFile-> {
          StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(selectedFile.getItem().get().getFileName(),
                  ()->fileInputHandlerService.fileInput(selectedFile.getItem().get()));
          anchor = new Anchor(resource,"a");
          anchor.getElement().setAttribute("download",true);
          anchor.setVisible(true);
          add(anchor);
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adjust your `fileDownloadRequestListener` to this and it should work:

```
    private ComponentEventListener<GridContextMenu.GridContextMenuItemClickEvent<FileEntity>> fileDownloadRequestListener() {
        return selectedFile -> {
            StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(selectedFile.getItem().get().getFileName(),
                    () -> fileInputHandlerService.fileInput(selectedFile.getItem().get()));
            anchor = new Anchor(resource, "a");
            Element element = anchor.getElement();
            element.setAttribute("download", true);
            // Hide the anchor from the user
            element.getStyle().set("display", "none");
            add(anchor);
            // Trigger click and remove when ready
          element.executeJs("return new Promise(resolve =>{this.click(); setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 150)})", element).then(jsonValue -> remove(anchor));
    }
```

Comment: it works really close to what I have expected. Button is functional. But problem is when I trigger anchor event , browser directly downloads a corrupted text file name "f.txt"  which is not present in the server and not expected file . Do you have any suggestions as to what problem could be?

Comment: You're right, @MEDOĞ . I didn't test it very well (I tested with a `FileInputStream`), but was able to reproduce the same behaviour. The problem was that the `anchor` was removed too early. The `StreamResource` removes the resource whenever the `anchor` is detached. After that the browser didn't have access to the resource. I changed the js code to use a`Promise` when triggering the `click` event in order to remove the `anchor` whenever it's ready. Therefore the `StreamResource` is able to generate the temporary `URL` and the browser is able to reach it. I updated the answer.

Comment: This works perfectly for me, thank you! I am also able to disable then re-enable the button the listener is registered to.

Answer (score 0):

```
Anchor download = new Anchor();
download.add(downloadButton);
download.getElement().setAttribute("download", "Hscodelistdownload.xlsx");
downloadButton.addClickListener(e -> {
                  
                 StreamResource resource = new StreamResource("Hscodelistdownload"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".xlsx", Exporter.exportAsExcel(grid));
                   download.setHref(resource);
                   Element element = download.getElement();
                   element.setAttribute("download", true);
                   element.getStyle().set("display", "none");
                   element.executeJs("return new Promise(resolve =>{this.click(); setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 150)})", element).then(jsonValue -> remove(download));
                   StreamRegistration regn = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getResourceRegistry().registerResource(resource);
                   UI.getCurrent().getPage().open(regn.getResourceUri().toString());
           
            });
add(downloadButton);
```